# Getting score timestamp in Google games services (Android)

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am trying to get a score timestamp like this:

```
public static void SavePlayerHighScoresInfo(LoadPlayerScoreResult result) {
    LeaderboardScore score = result.getScore();
    if(score != null) {
         string valuescore = score.getDisplayScore();
         long timestampscore = score.getTimestampMillis();
         //At this point "timestampscore" is 0 but value score is correct
         //...Save info
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am using the [getTimestampMillis()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/LeaderboardScore.html#getTimestampMillis()) method. I think this should return the correct timestamp, but it is returning 0. Other information in score object seems to be correct (valuescore, username).

The game is published on Google Play Developer Console, but I am using a test account (application is only on aplha testing fase).

Any suggestion on what is happening?

**Update**

The method I'm using to get the score is this one: [loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/Leaderboards.html#loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int)) that returns me an object `Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult` which should be filled with the information.

Comment: How is the value returned by score.getTimestampMillis() set? If you could throw up some code from the LeaderboardScore class it would be useful

Comment: @nyx See my update. The value shoul be set in google servers. Am I right?

Comment: show your code, how are you initializing it.

Comment: What is the status of the result? If it is `STATUS_OK`, I would expect the timestamp to be set as you say, but if it is `STATUS_NETWORK_ERROR_STALE_DATA`, it probably would not have the timestamp set, as described here: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult.html

Comment: @myanimal The status is `STATUS_OK`. I don't understand why other properties are set but not the timestamp...

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Google+ Android Basic Samples](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples), you can start from an example to see the timestamps correctly stored in leaderboard scores.

The following code shows you how to retrieve the top 5 scores:

```
Games.Leaderboards.loadTopScores(mGoogleApiClient,getString(R.string.leaderboard_easy),
    LeaderboardVariant.TIME_SPAN_ALL_TIME, LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_PUBLIC, 5).setResultCallback(
        new ResultCallback<Leaderboards.LoadScoresResult>() {
            public void onResult(Leaderboards.LoadScoresResult arg0) {
                int size = arg0.getScores().getCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    LeaderboardScore lbs = arg0.getScores().get(i);
                    String name = lbs.getScoreHolderDisplayName();
                    String score = lbs.getDisplayScore();
                    long millis = lbs.getTimestampMillis();
                    Uri urlimage = lbs.getScoreHolderHiResImageUri();
                }
            }
        });
```

The correct values should appear where submitted in `millis`. Scores are being submitted as:

```
Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(mGoogleApiClient, getString(R.string.leaderboard_easy),
        mOutbox.mEasyModeScore);
```

Answer (score -1):

`loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore returns 0 in getTimestampMillis()`. Maybe that method do not make a call to the online_public leaderboards services because it is not necessary. Maybe it retrieves data from some_stored_local_data, which don't need a timestamp. Anyway, my near solution: Try using `loadPlayerCenteredScores()` instead. Setting its max_results to 1.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: i'm still thinking that mine is a solution; loadPlayerCenteredScores() returns correct "player" score and timestamp, in the first "accepted" answer uses loadTopScores() which return topScores and not player scores. Maybe the missunderstood was because of my english level.

Comment: The problem is that you started your answer with *I faced the same problem* sentence and that is against stack overflow guidelines. You should never start an answer like that.